# How to configure a website using Flutter Web to not cache data?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, flutter-web

I am creating a website using Flutter Web. The website is in production and we release one version a week. Some users have trouble getting the new version of the web application. I would like to set my website to not cache data.

I added these tags, but to no succes:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Comment: Are you using a CDN or edge provider?  Generally you should favor setting the HTTP response header for Caching instead of the meta tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a decision for your team, but you wouldn't be fine working with `versioned URLS`? That is the easiest trick I know for cache invalidation.
In the `index.html` file you can pass a unique VERSION_CODE to your `main javascript bundle file` before requesting it like

`<script src="main.dart.js?VERSION_CODE=7672" type="application/javascript"></script>`

And then everytime before doing a `flutter build web` you need to update the VERSION_CODE of your index.html file, thus invalidating the client side when they request your bundle. You can automate this, but there's no way to pass environment variables to `flutter build web` step.

Comment: I have tried this solution but I was not successful. It is necessary to update the browser a few times for it to work correctly.